# Converting PNG to DDS with PHP and Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Users can create their own Skin on our Webpage for the Game we play. After creating their Skins, i must convert them into DDS Files for them. So i would save many time if Imagick can convert direct into an BC3 DXT5 DDS File.

```
$img = new Imagick('test.png'); //Load the uploaded image
$img->setformat('dds'); //Set the format to dds
$img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_DXT5); //Set compression method
$img->writeimage('test.dds'); //Write/save the dds texture
```

PNG to convert: [test.png](http://zg15.de/www/sofa/alpha/test.png)
Converted DDS: [test.dds](http://zg15.de/www/sofa/alpha/test.dds)

If i convert a PNG Image with that code above, i get a dds File which looks in a Hex Editor like a mess. The Header is complete broken.
I also can't open the dds File in Photoshop (with dds Plugin) because Photoshop say "Can't open the File because the Filesformat can't be interpret".

**Versions i use:**

PHP Version 7.1.6-nmm1 (other PHP Versions change nothing)
imagick module version 3.4.3RC1
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2016-11-29 Q16
 Imagick using ImageMagick library version ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2017-07-31 Q16

I use the PHP Version because i have just a normal Webspace. The code didnt work on 2 different Webspaces so i think the dds convert in Imagick is broken.

Is the PHP Code wrong or Imagick DDS broken.
Any Idea's ?

Comment: I do not know Imagick well. But from the Imagemagick formats page: `Use -define to specify the compression (e.g. -define dds:compression={dxt1, dxt5, none}). Other defines include dds:cluster-fit={true,false}, dds:weight-by-alpha={true,false}, dds:fast-mipmaps={true,false}, and use dds:mipmaps to set the number of mipmaps (use fromlist to use the image list).` So Imagick setImageCompression may not work for DDS. What happens if you leave off that line in your code? Does it work? In Imagemagick 6.9.9.18 command line, this works fine for me: `convert test.png test.dds`

Comment: One other way to test your Imagemagick version would be to run my command `convert test.png test.dds` via PHP exec() and see if produces a valid file. That way, you can tell if it is Imagemagick or Imagick where the problem exists.

Comment: Is DDS a *"Microsoft Direct Draw Surface"*? Can you hex dump the first 50-80 bytes of a valid DDS file? And then the IM-created DDS file? Why are you using an ancient 4+ year old IM version?

Comment: @fmw42 , i can create a dds file with PHP exec() which i didnt know it work without to know the converter path. It produce the same dds file and content as my PHP code above. Other defines Options from the list change also nothing. @Mark Setchell , it is "Microsoft Direct Draw Surface" and because it is just a normal webspace without access to modules, the php.ini ect. i can`t change the IM Version to a newer one.

Comment: `@Mark Setchell` Those version of 6.7.7.10 have been patched without upgrading the original version number. You can tell by the dates associated with the version. However, there have been times that the patches have not been done properly. Nevertheless, likely both patches, esp. the first one are not current. I have heard that some patches were not done properly or need to be replaced by more current patches. However, I do not know much about Imagick and how it used patched versions of Imagemagick.

Comment: I wrote an Email to the Provider and ask for other IM Versions over    <usr/bin/...> or a update of IM. They use Ubuntuu System with Security updates and the newest Version i can get is 6.8.9-9. The whole Webserver must be installed on a new Server and the benefits from our old contract gets lost. Thanks for all the help, i will not update because of the old and better contract.